# How to prove boolean ordering question

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let $\sqsubseteq$ be the boolean ordering of $X$, so for every $x$ and $y$ applies $x \sqsubseteq y$ if $x \sqcap y = x$. Let $v, w, a, b \in X$ with $v \sqsubseteq a$ and $w \sqsubseteq b$. Show that $v \sqcup w \sqsubseteq a\sqcup b$ and $v \sqcap w \sqsubseteq a\sqcap b$.

Should this be solved algebraically, or in a different way? And if so, where would be my starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Work up to it in steps:

1. Show that if $x\sqsubseteq y$, then $x\sqcap a\sqsubseteq y\sqcap a$.
2. Show that if $x\sqsubseteq y$, then $x\sqcup a\sqsubseteq y\sqcup a$; you may find it helpful to show first that $x\sqsubseteq y$ iff $x\sqcup y=y$.
3. Apply (1) and (2) twice to get the desired results.

Comment: Well, I can reason that if $x\sqsubseteq y$ (thinking about it in a sets way) that $x$ is contained in $y$. With $a$, two scenario's (well actually three) can happen: either $a$ is contained in $x$, $x$ is contained in $a$, or $x$ is equal to $a$. If $a$ is contained in $x$, that would mean that $x\sqcap a$ would result in $a$. Then that would als mean that $y\sqcap a$ would result in $a$, and so $a\sqsubseteq a$, which is true. On the other hand, if $x$ is contained in $a$, then $x\sqcap a$ would result in $x$ and $y \sqcup a$ would result in $a$. $x\sqsubseteq a$, which is true.

Comment: But saying this is different than putting it down in algebraic formula's!

Comment: @Garth: Don’t bother thinking about the power set algebra. If $x\sqsubseteq y$, then $x\sqcap y=x$, so $$(x\sqcap a)\sqcap(y\sqcap a)=(x\sqcap y)\sqcap   a=x\sqcap a\;,$$ and therefore $x\sqcap a\sqsubseteq y\sqcap a$. I used only the commutativity and associativity of $\sqcap$ and the identity $z\sqcap z=z$. // If $x\sqsubseteq y$, then $$(x\sqcup y)\sqcap y=(x\sqcap y)\sqcup(y\sqcap y)=(x\sqcap y)\sqcup y=x\sqcup y\;,$$ so $x\sqcup y\sqsubseteq y$; ...

Comment: ... and $y\sqsubseteq x\sqcup y$ follows from one of the [absorption axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29#Definition) for Boolean algebras. I’ll leave the rest of (2) and all of (3) for you to try.

Comment: I think I might get it, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Garth: You’re welcome. Let me know if you get stuck on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- What you want to prove is that $\sqcup$ and $\sqcap$ are monotone with respect to $\sqsubseteq$.
- Start with a simple example: prove that the ordinary set operations $\cup$ and $\cap$ are monotone with respect to subset relation $\subseteq$, i.e.

\begin{align}
A_1 \subseteq A_2 \land B_1 \subseteq B_2\quad &\implies\quad A_1 \cup B_1 \subseteq A_2 \cup B_2 \\
A_1 \subseteq A_2 \land B_1 \subseteq B_2\quad &\implies\quad A_1 \cap B_1 \subseteq A_2 \cap B_2
\end{align}

- Transform your proof so that is uses only set-operations and related theorems and axioms.
- Try to make the proof work for an arbitrary boolean algebra.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction! I'm not quite sure what you mean with what you wrote with the sets; IFF A is a real subset of A` and B which is a real subset, THEN the union of A and B are a subset of A` and B`. What is meant with A` and B`?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi Nothing in particular. I changed the notation, is this more clear?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction. It is more clear, though I have to really take the time to think about it. I'll do this tomorrow, since it's late here and I really need to go catch some sleep.